# Synchronous initalisation of multiple Observables/Promises in ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im relative new to Angular/typescript and have following problem. Probably very trivial for most of you.
In my `ngOnInit()` im trying to retrieve settings stored in my backend via a GET request. Afterwards i need to start to subscribe to an observable. The observable is starting to fill the widgets (content wise/they change over time) while the settings give me the number/type of widgets that will be shown.

Basically, to have the ngOnInit() wait for the `getGeneralSettingsOnce` response and afterwards to start some other subscriptions.

**My request function:**

```
getGeneralSettingsOnce(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}/get_general_settings`).toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      return response
    })
  }
```

My first attempt was to just make the ngOnInit of my main page an async function and await the promise. -> This leads to the `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '-1')` for some static  widgets within my main page. According to an article i read this might be caused because my main page is not completly loaded while the browser is already tyring to render the page?(Not quiet sure) Source: [article](https://dev.to/jdgamble555/forcing-angular-to-wait-on-your-async-function-2ck1#:%7E:text=ngOnInit%20does%20NOT%20wait%20for%20the%20promise%20to,data%20%3D%20await%20this.service.getData%28%29.pipe%28take%281%29%29.toPromise%28%29%3B%20this.data%20%3D%20this.modifyMyData%28data%29%3B%20%7D)

**Parts of my ngOnInit of my main page**

```
async ngOnInit() {  
    let generalSettings = await this.localService.getGeneralSettingsOnce(); //calling the promise
    this.widgetCount = generalSettings.widget_count

    // other subsrciptions
    this.localService.getWidgetContent().subscribe(
      data => { this.loadWidgetContent(data)
      } 
    }
}
```

So my question is how can i archive my goal to init the settings first and subsribe to other request functions afterwards like it would be synchronous. Preferable without getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for a `subscribe` (common way to get data from observables) combined with [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) , which can execute one observable after another!

```
    subscription: Subscription = new Subscription(); // <- stores observables to unsubscribe

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription.add( // <- add the subscription to a single place
            this.localService
                .getGeneralSettingsOnce()
                .pipe(
                    switchMap(generalSettings => {
                        this.widgetCount = generalSettings.widget_count;
                        // other subsrciptions
                        return this.localService.getWidgetContent();
                    })
                )
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.loadWidgetContent(data);
                })
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // <- subscribers must be unsubscribed to prevent memory leaks
    }
```